# Trigger a createAsyncThunk to POST additional data from within a createSlice? Possible?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I have 2 APIs, one is to add an MMA fighter to the fighters table, and I have another api to get all the weight classes to populate one of my menus, if I am adding a fighter whose weight class currently does NOT exist in the weightclass table, I will need to add that new weightclass record thru my weightclass api endpoint.

so here is my first call to add a new fighter:

```
export const addFighter = createAsyncThunk(
  'fighters/addFighter',
  async (fighter: fighterInterface, { dispatch }) => {
    return fetch('fightersAPIEndpoint/fighters', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(fighter),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    }).then((res) => res.json())
       .then(() => {
         dispatch(checkWeightClass(fighter.weightclass))
       })
  }
)
```

and the **checkWeightClass** reducer is inside my createSlice, I need to check whether this new fighter's weightclass currently exists before adding it, so I have logic in **checkWeightClass** to check for that:

```
checkWeightClass: (state, { payload }) => {
      let findWeightClass = state.weightclasses.find((w) => {
        if (w.name === payload) {
          return true
        }
      })

      if (findWeightClass) {
      } else {      
        // if the weightclass doesn't exist, I will want to call this other createAsyncThunk
        dispatch(addWeightClass(payload))
      }
}
```

But it doesn't let me, how do I accomplish this? I can't just call the addWeightClass API right away because I need to check whether it exists or not first, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dispatching an action inside a reducer is a [bad practice](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#reducers-must-not-have-side-effects). a reducer should only handle the changes in state with no side effects.

One alternative for that is to dispatch `addWeightClass` action inside `addFighter`, and to do the check inside the callback from the api:

```js
async (fighter: fighterInterface, { dispatch, getState }) => {
    const { weightclasses } = getState().fighters; // Absolute path from redux state
    return fetch('fightersAPIEndpoint/fighters', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(fighter),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
       .then((res) => res.json())
       .then(() => {
           const findWeightClass = weightclasses.find((w) => w.name = fighter.weightclass);
           if (!findWeightClass) {
               dispatch(addWeightClass(fighter.weightclass));
           }
       })
  }
```

Put attention that `getState` retrieves the entire state, not just the relative path like the reducers.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try!
I came up with a workaround by creating more properties in my state to track whether I should call the addWeightClass createAsyncThunk function, but your solution is a lot more elegant if it works, will report back!